# How to find out which item containing a specific string was clicked?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

my current code obtains items from a string array but how can the array be used to perform specific actions for specific strings? E.g. If I click the item containing the string "Anpan", I want a specific event to happen.

**strings.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Breads</string>
    
    <!--Array (198 items)-->
    <string-array name="array_breads">
        <item>Aish merahrah</item>
        ...
        <item>Zwieback</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private var itemArray: Array<String>? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        itemArray = resources.getStringArray(R.array.array_breads)

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            AdaptiveTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    MyScaffold(itemArray = itemArray as Array<out String>)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MyScaffold(itemArray: Array<out String>) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            SmallTopAppBar(
                title = {
                    Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.breads))
                }
            )
        },
        content = {
            val listState = rememberLazyListState()

            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                state = listState,
                contentPadding = PaddingValues(top = 64.dp, bottom = 80.dp),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(4.dp)
                ) {
                items(itemArray) { item ->
                    Text(modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp), text = item,
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleLarge)
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems too basic to be a post but here we go.

```
val comparableString = stringResource(R.string.anpan) //Initialise here

LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                state = listState,
                contentPadding = PaddingValues(top = 64.dp, bottom = 80.dp),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(4.dp)
                ) {
                items(itemArray) { item ->
                    Text(
                          modifier = Modifier
                                      .padding(16.dp)
                                      .clickable {
                                         if(item == comparableString) //Compare here
                                            performSpecificTask()
                                         else performGeneralTask()
                                      },
                        text = item,
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleLarge)
                }
            }
```

Here `doSpecificTask()` and `doGeneral...` is in reference to the task that you wish to do over there. Just replace the calls with your own code blocks, just to be clear.

Comment: What about a string resource? `if (item == stringResource(id = R.string.anpan))` did not work for me.

Comment: Sir @Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable. `stringResource(...)` is a Composable and so you can't invoke it inside an `onClick` method which is not a Composable. Just fetch thr value outside of the `Button` Composable and store it in a variable. Then simply use that value inside of it.

Comment: I haven't seen any example code hence that's why I asked this question. Would I do something like `var clickedItem = String()`?

Answer (score 1):

Add clickable modifier on your Text component:

```
LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                state = listState,
                contentPadding = PaddingValues(top = 64.dp, bottom = 80.dp),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(4.dp)
                ) {
                items(itemArray) { item ->
                    Text(modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(16.dp)
                            .clickable{// You can obtain 'item' here which item clicked.}, 
                         text = item,
                         style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleLarge)
                }
            }
```

Comment: Unresolved reference `onClick`

Comment: sorry 'clickable' modifier instead

Comment: what kind of code need to go inside the modifier to detect a specific string? I know an if statement would need to be used. I can't find any examples.

Comment: you can find specific string with itemArray[index] or you can clicked text item in i mention that in answer, like: .clickable{ pritnln( item )}